# How to Concatenate multiple columns with a comma if all are empty then showing #value

Tags: excel, vba

This [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27689666/how-to-concatenate-multiple-columns-if-not-empty) nearly solve my problem but one small problem remains.

```
Function MyConcat(ConcatArea As Range) As String
  For Each x In ConcatArea: xx = IIf(x = "", xx & "", xx & x & "-"): Next
  MyConcat = Left(xx, Len(xx) - 1)
End Function
```

If all of selected cell values are empty then in excel sheet the cell output showing #value.
I want to show a dash if all cell are empty.
How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Enclose your UDF solution in an `IFERROR` statement, such as: `=IFERROR(myudf(xxxx),"-")`

Comment: (If you don't have `IfError()`, you can use `=If(IsErr(myUDF(xxxx)),"-","")`)

Answer (score 2):

There are really two fixes you can apply in your case:

The first fix is to modify your UDF to detect the error condition before it returns, then just make sure your UDF returns the string `"-"`:

```
Function MyConcat(ConcatArea As Range) As String
  For Each x In ConcatArea: xx = IIf(x = "", xx & "", xx & x & "-"): Next
  If Len(xx) = 0 Then
    MyConcat = "-"
  Else
    MyConcat = Left(xx, Len(xx) - 1)
  End If
End Function
```

The second fix works inside the worksheet cell by wrapping your call to the UDF within an error checking formula. Here's an example:

```
=IFERROR(myudf(xxxx), "-")
```

> **EDIT:** added error checking to your OP code. I would also recommend breaking your single-line `If` statement into multiple lines. As a general practice, it makes your code far easier to debug. Stepping through your UDF showed me that the `#Value` error you received was because you were passing a `Length` parameter of `-1` to the `Left` function.

Comment: I want to solve it in UDF . The UDF is given in the question.